# DHCP Randomly Not Assigning Addresses

Tags: windows-server-2003, dhcp, dhcp-server

Having a strange issue for the past day or so. Some users (probably about a dozen, dozen and a half out of 100 or so) are having trouble pulling DHCP. They are getting the private IP address. If I disable/enable the network adapter and do a Repair on the connection, eventually it pulls an IP address.

I checked the DHCP server and I didn't see any errors. I restarted the DHCP service yesterday when it was happening with no fix. I rebooted the server last night to hopefully fix it this morning. Some users are still complaining that the issue is still occurring.

I'm completely stumped at this point. I ran a tool to look for rogue DHCP servers and it found nothing. The users that are having trouble getting DHCP are connected to different switches at different parts of the building, so I can't imagine it's the switch. DHCP is running on a Windows 2003 server.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The other strange thing is that the Windows 7 clients keep switching to Public network as well.

Comment: The troubled clients wouldn't happen to be connected to separate vlans/subnets from the ones not having this issue?